# Go GAE and file upload without having to post form and go to other site

Tags: google-app-engine, file-upload, go, http-post

I am trying to make a image upload service with Google App Engine application in Golang.

I have already followed this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/). And it works just fine. However the problem appears when uploading big images, because it takes time and doesn't look good.

I am looking for a way to upload image without having to POST form and recieve the image via other service.

Could anyone please provide me an example of similar site or even a hint.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't use the blobstore for this.  Why doesn't it look good? Why not use a POST?